# Design a branching algorithm breaking the triviality barrier for 3-SAT problem

Tags: algorithm, boolean-operations, sat

I am working on an example that says:
For 3-SAT problem we have clause c=l1 or l2 or l3. How many satisfying assignments are possible. Considering these assignments, design a branching algorithm breaking the triviality barrier.

I am new to this and my question is not on the solution, but on the interpretation of the question:

1. In my understanding there are 2^3=8 possible solutions, 7 of each are satisfying. Does the question ask to find these assignments or to find number of possible solutions, because there will be always 7 possible solutions for such clause.
2. What does it mean to break the triviality barrier, does it mean not to use brute force to find all possible assignments and count correct?
3. Any directions or better interpretation would be welcome.

Comment: I might be less "new to this", yet I have exactly the same confusion as you when reading the question. Your understanding of the total number of possible assignments and the number of satisfying assignment is correct. But I have no idea what "breaking the triviality barrier" might mean; they ask you to design an algorithm, but I don't even know what problem your algorithm should solve.

Comment: Exploiting the symmetry of the expression, it is enough to try FFF, TFF, TTF, TTT, which is linear rather than exponential in the number of variables. Hence, 3+3+1 solutions. (For what it is worth.)

Comment: As others have said, "triviality barrier" is a nebulous term. If that came from a teacher, I'd look for a different course. I guess it means "not generating every possible assignment of true and false, testing them in the expression".  A simple place to start is to look up branch and bound algorithms. The general idea is to skip over variable assignments that can't possibly satisfy the expression due to something in its structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The “trivial” algorithm here branches on each variable recursively and then evaluates the formula. The observation here is that, by branching on at most three variables at a time and discarding the obviously infeasible assignment, we end up branching 7 ways for each three variables instead of 8.
2. I’d say breaching triviality means finding an algorithm that’s O(2^(delta n)) for some delta < 1. Using the hint you should be able to get an O(7^(n/3) poly(n))-time algorithm, which qualifies.

Comment: I think I agree with you. For now I designed the algorithm that finds 7 solutions, which means it runs 2^n-1=7 times.

Can you elaborate the O(7^(n/3)) time? I though here we fix the n=3 meaning that the time would be a constant.

Comment: @Engineeringbridges 3SAT formulas have many clauses. So the algorithm is: 0. The empty conjunction is satisfiable by definition. 1. Otherwise, pick a clause. 2. For each satisfying assignment for that clause, propagate those assignments to the rest of the formula and determine recursively if this derived formula is satisfiable. 3. The formula is satisfiable if and only if at least one of the recursive calls is.